# Automaximize scroll height in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I add 1pt to the height of the last cell and am scrolled to the bottom of the screen entirely the cell will move off the screen. If I am scrolled to the bottom of the screen entirely and subtract 1pt from the height of the last cell, the cell stays on the screen entirely.

The height difference in both cases is effectively being applied to the bottom of the cell.

I want to effectively apply it to the top of the cell when it is being added instead.

This way the cells above the last one will move up and the cell at the bottom of the screen won't move off the screen.

How can I achieve this?

Edit:

I've already tried setting the scroll height every time I change the size, but it's slow and glitchy (a black bar flashes on and off at the top of the screen).

Comment: There's a method for setting the scroll position of the tableView.  You'll probably need to implement this immediately after resizing the cell.

Comment: @maxhud - you recently approved [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3411520). Can you explain why you think that is a good edit? Sorry to post this here, but I felt like either you are not checking the edits you review, or you know something I don't know about that edit. Even if the answer should have been removed, that is what flags are for, not edits...

Comment: @Gray I misunderstood it as a question. I didn't realize that was the answer to a question. Sorry about that.